# R KNN Error - Error in knn(training_data, validation_data, training_data$Award., k = 7) : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r

I got the following error when I try to do a KNN fit on my data.

```
knn_fit = knn(training_data,validation_data,training_data$Award.,k=7)
```

> `Error in knn(training_data, validation_data, training_data$Award., k = 7) : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths`

Could someone help me figure out this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The train and validate data shouldn't have the target column. For your dataset, remove 'Award' column from the both train and test. But, before removing column don't forget to save the target column into another data frame (`label<- training_data$Award`).